# Error: Command "require-commerce" is not defined, while Magento 2.4.4 upgrade

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, magento2.4.4

I am trying to upgrade to commerce enterprise edition 2.4.4 from 2.3.6 but it's failing with error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "require-commerce" is not defined.
```

Please check screenshot:
[image]

> If any idea, Please guide me. Thanks in Advance!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is a better solution. From the docs (which I missed the first time): https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer update
```

**Original answer:**

Just use `composer require` instead of `composer require-commerce`. I came accross the same lines in the docs. I don't know why.

Using the other command runs successfully. I just did an upgrade couple of minutes ago with this approach.

Comment: Actually after upgrading to 2.4.4, it's not changed root composer.json file version. Still it was 2.3.6 before and it's changed only in require-dev{} tag. Any idea please.

Comment: Do you mean the `"version"` tag in the root of the composer.json file? You can edit it yourself. My experience is that composer does not change it. When you see the right version in the backend, you can be sure it succeeded ;)

Comment: okay, Thanks :)

Comment: You can accept the answer if it is correct, so you help others.

Comment: Please check the other answer by Marcin J

Answer (score 10):

Please try to run:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin --no-update
composer update
```

prior to

```
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update
```

Comment: As mentioned, you must now update the composer-root-update-plugin first. See : https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html
So now, the magento installation requires this composer-root-update-plugin: "The Composer plugin resolves changes that must be made to the root project composer.json file before updating to a new product requirement.

The plugin partially automates the manual upgrade by identifying and helping you resolve dependency conflicts instead of requiring you to identify and fix them manually."

Answer (score 1):

Below points worked for me while upgrade to Magento 2.4.4 EE

```
 php bin/magento maintenance:enable

 composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update

 composer update
```

> take back up of composer.json

```
 composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.4 --no-update

 composer update
```

> Please run below commands after successful upgrade:

```
 php bin/magento cache:clean

 php bin/magento cache:flush

 php bin/magento setup:upgrade

 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

 php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After `setup:static-content:deploy -f` command If you want to use `setup:di:compile` command you can do it but It might be throw some errors we can do it later.

Just for cross checking version upgraded or not, upgrade and deploy command is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error

```
 "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "magento/magento-composer-installer": false,
            "magento/inventory-composer-installer": false,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": false,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": false,
            "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": false,
            "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": true
        }
    },
```

That was false here "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": true